# In content.js file; How does one set a background image on an element?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

i'm unsuccesfully trying to set a background image on an element in a content.js file. Its in base64 format

`theElement[0].style["background"] = url('data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSU...ectt');`

setting the background in devtools works but not in the extension?

Comment: It means the element doesn't exist at the time the content script runs. You can check this in devtools debugger or by using console.log(theElement[0]); If I'm right, you need setTimeout or MutationObserver.

Comment: but this works         theElement[0].style["background"] = 'yellow';

Comment: console error: Error in event handler: ReferenceError: url is not defined

Comment: Yes, and to fix that error you need the quotemarks: theElement[0].style["background"] = "url('data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSU...ectt')";